# Is it possible to replace elements of a list with a "for in" iteration in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, for-in-loop

I'm trying to iterate over a list and change its values with a "for in" loop:

```
example_string = "This is a string."

for char in example_string :
    char = 'r'

example_list = list(example_string)

for char in example_list:
    char = 'r'
```

The string object is not modified by the iteration.

Does the "for in" iteration in Python returns another variable and not the actual list/string element?

I tried doing it with lists. I expected that the items in the list or string would get changed by the assignment.

Comment: Could you be more specific of what you are trying to do? And where is the list in your code?

Comment: @aelian did you manage to do what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can change in a list, but use the index instead:

```py
example_string = ["This is a string.", "This is another string"]

for i in range(len(example_string)):
    example_string[i] = "r"

print(example_string)
```

[image]

In your example, only the variable would change:

```py
example_string = "This is a string."

for char in example_string:
    char = 'r'
    print(char)
```

[image]

You can select from your string using the index as well, however the [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) itself is immutable and you can't reassign directly in it:

> Textual data in Python is handled with str objects, or strings. Strings are immutable sequences of Unicode code points.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a function in which you create a new list (or string) and append the changed elements in your for-in loop. An example of what I mean:

```
def change_in_list(_list):
  new_list = []
  for element in _list:
    element = 'CHANGED'
    new_list.append(element)
  return new_list

example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(example_list)
print(change_in_list(example_list))
```

[output from list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvTKy.png)

For a string you would use

```
def modify_string(_string):
  new_string = ''
  for character in _string:
    character = 'CHANGED'
    new_string += character
  return new_string

example_string = 'Hello World'
print(example_string)
print(modify_string(example_string))
```

The output here is [string output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLrET.png)

Both can be modified/adapted to your needs but I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes its definitely possible with a for loop but you are not changing the original variable: example_string in your code. Try creating a new list and append or insert the new value in every iteration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).